# Visual Studio .gitignore file type in directory subtree

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'd like to ignore all *.js files in one of my project folders because we're using TypeScript and *.js are products of compiler.

If I put this into the .gitignore

`/src/MyWebApp/App/**/*.js`

`git status` correctly ignores the files, but Visual Studio 2013 still shows them as untracked.

Any idea how to make Visual Studio ignore them too?